# outputing dictionary optimally

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, disk-io

i have 4 dictionarys that contain 800k strings with 200 to 6000 characters.
when i load it into memory it takes up about 11 gigs of memory.
it is taking me 2 minutes to parse the data and 2 minutes to output the data.
is there anyway to output the data faster than what i am using below?
I am only getting 20-31 MB per second disk IO and I know the hard drive can do 800ish

```
var hash1 = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>(f.Count + 2);
var hash2 = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>(f.Count + 2);
var hash3 = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>(f.Count + 2);
var hash4 = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>(f.Count + 2);
....
foreach (var me in mswithfilenames)
{
    filename = me.Key.ToString();
    string filenamef = filename + "index1";
    string filenameq = filename + "index2";
    string filenamefq = filename + "index3";
    string filenameqq = filename + "index4";

    StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filenamef);
    StreamWriter sw2 = File.AppendText(filenameq);
    StreamWriter swq = File.AppendText(filenamefq);
    StreamWriter sw2q = File.AppendText(filenameqq);

    for (i = 0; i <= totalinhash; i++)
    {
        if (hashs1[i].ContainsKey(filenamef))
        {
            sw.Write(hashs1[i][filenamef]);
        }
        if (hashs2[i].ContainsKey(filenameq))
        {
            sw2.Write(hashs2[i][filenameq]);
        }
        if (hashs3[i].ContainsKey(filenamefastaq))
        {
            swq.Write(hash4[i][filenamefastaq]);
        }

        if (hash4[i].ContainsKey(filenameqq))
        {
            sw2q.Write(hash4[i][filenameqq]);
        }
    }

    sw.Close();
    sw2.Close();
    sw3.Close();
    sw4.Close();
    swq.Close();
    sw2q.Close();
}
```

Comment: At a glance you are performing twice as many hash lookups as required.  Use `Dictionary.TryGetValue` instead.  If that returns false you know it doesn't exist, if it returns true you already have your value.  Left as a comment because I don't have time to analyze the problem at a higher level.  Also.... `using` blocks are your friend.  What happens if any of those calls to `Write` throw an exception?  You won't clean up after your streams as quickly as you would like.

Comment: This might be a better question for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) since you aren't actually encountering a problem.

Comment: @M.Babcock thanks i posted it in code review

Comment: @Tigran mswithfilenames has the filenames that i am using to output the hashes to the correct place

Comment: @EdS. thanks for the trygetvalue idea i have been use to using hashtables :) i'm not concerned if the writes throw and exception because it would trigger in the debugger and would mean that some major unrecoverable problem has happened and i'd just have to start the program over :)

Comment: @caseyr547: You should be concerned though.  There is no reason not to wrap those in a `using` block.  It is more robust and adds no complexity to your program.  The fact that the error cannot be recovered from is irrelevant; this is about deterministic resource deallocation.

Comment: @EdS. trygetvalue had no impact on performance

Comment: @caseyr547: Because that's likely not your bottleneck.  Still, no reason to perform more lookups than is necessary.

Comment: Your code does not look complete either. (You close more streams than you open.) Use more descriptive file names (hashs1-4 are bad!), and try to avoid duplicate code. This looks really repetitive. What are you actually trying to do? :D (Parallelization could help, but if disk I/O is not high enough for that, as has been pointed out, all of these problems may not be the performance killer you are searching for. :))

Comment: @hangy your right i took out two trivial streams because they have no impact on anything good catch... i do have more discriptive names in the code but i dont want to share those because it reveals the nature of the work...i tried parralization with before when it was hashtables and everything crashed...i'll try it with the dictionaries and see if it works...thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: @M.Babcock - No, this isn't for code-review. The lack of `using`s might be but there is an actual technical issue here: speed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Aren't code reviews also concerned with performance problems? The code functions, so isn't that the end of the line for SO's use?

Comment: @M.Babcock: SO is full of "how to do X better" questions.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Agreed, but it's also full of a lot of other questions that don't conform to SO's FAQ. I'll see if I can find a meta post on it (and if I can't then I'll ask a question there).

Comment: @HenkHolterman - [The meta opinion on the topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127319/where-is-the-line-between-code-review-and-so/127320#127320) (so far at least, maybe it'll flip)

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions across SE sites as it creates unnecessary duplication and hassle for people on both sites.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn sorry i wont cross post again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most expensive part is the I/O. And this loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= totalinhash; i++)
{
    if (hashs1[i].ContainsKey(filenamef))
    {
        sw.Write(hashs1[i][filenamef]);
    }
    if (hashs2[i].ContainsKey(filenameq))
    {
        sw2.Write(hashs2[i][filenameq]);
    }
    ...
}
```

is alternating between different files. That will probably cause some extra head-movement and it creates fragmented files (slowing future actions on those files).

I would use:

```
for (i = 0; i <= totalinhash; i++)
{
    if (hashs1[i].ContainsKey(filenamef))
    {
        sw.Write(hashs1[i][filenamef]);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i <= totalinhash; i++)
{
    if (hashs2[i].ContainsKey(filenameq))
    {
        sw2.Write(hashs2[i][filenameq]);
    }
}
...
```

But of course you should measure this. It won't make much difference on SSDs for instance, only on mechanical disks.

Comment: thanks i'm on a mechanical disk and i'll check the performance in a few moments

Answer (score 3):

Did you measure anything? It sounds like you have non trivial amount of data to read and write - so first step would be to establish absolute baseline for your disk subsystem on how fast it reads/writes that much of data. Simple read of the file followed by write to new file of approximate amount of data you expect will show how far you can go in optimizing it.

You may fine that your code itself does not take too much more time over reading/writing.

Comment: yes i did measure the times and simply copy and pasteing the files from one folder to another takes about 3 second (2.5gigs with the hard drive that i have at 855meg/s). i'd like to get the writing from memory that fast too.

Answer (score 1):

Can you have a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, myCustomDataHolder>>` rather than four separate parallel `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>`?  Not only should it reduce the space consumed quite a lot, but it means 1/4 the dictionary lookups.

It's not quite clear if the dictionaries are entirely parallel given your question, but it seems likely enough to me.

Comment: the information in each of the dictionarys is unique to that hash i dont really know how i could merge them

Comment: You're using the filename as the key in all of the dictionaries, you're just appending an 'index1' 'index2' etc. to each one.  If you're populating those dictionaries in the same manor just use the plain filename as the key without appending 'index1' etc.  If the data already has 'index1' appended could you remove it?

Comment: let me think about that for a few minutes that seems like i might make a bug if i tried to do it haha :)

Comment: +1, maybe not the correct answer to this specific question, but a correct answer to many others

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that

```
if (hashs1[i].ContainsKey(filenamef))
{
   sw.Write(hashs1[i][filenamef]);
}
```

Takes 2 hash table accesses. One for the contains key, and one for the actual access. Many dictionary accesses can add up, so you can halve these accesses by using the dictionary tryGetValue method. This will combine these two calls into one. I could explain how this works, but this does the job better than I could: http://www.dotnetperls.com/trygetvalue